# how to assign values to variables in a for loop

Tags: javascript

Im trying to build a simple script that generate 2 random numbers from 1-6 (like a dice) and than loop the results 100 times and each time when one of the scenarios is true, adding +1 to the variable that represent the number of times the scenario is happened in each option and than show the results in an alert. It doesn't seem to work. Where I get wrong? Thank you!

```js
var diceOne = Math.random();
var calcDiceOne = (diceOne * 6) + 1;
calcDiceOne = Math.floor(calcDiceOne);

var diceTwo = Math.random();
var calcDiceTwo = (diceTwo * 6) + 1;
calcDiceTwo = Math.floor(calcDiceTwo);

var playerOneWon = 0;
var playerTwoWon = 0;
var Tie = 0;



for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    if (calcDiceOne(i) > calcDiceTwo(i)) {
      playerOneWon = playerOneWon++;
    }

    else if (calcDiceOne(i) < calcDiceTwo(i) {
      playerTwoWon = playerTwoWon++; 
    }

    else if (calcDiceOne(i) === calcDiceTwo(i)) {
      Tie = Tie++;
    }
}

alert(playerOneWon , playerTwoWon , Tie)
```

Comment: You're missing a `)` here: `if (calcDiceOne(i) < calcDiceTwo(i) ******** {`. Just clicking `Run code snippet` in your questions reports "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { on line 33"

Comment: Your `if () else if () else if ()` is incorrect. You should throw the dice only once in each loop.

Comment: Also `calcDiceOne` and `calcDiceTwo` are not functions, so the `(i)` should be dropped from them. Your first seven lines (including the blank line) should be inside your loop.

Comment: calcDiceOne(i) > calcDiceTwo(i) <--- calcDiceOne and calcDiceTwo are not functions....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues with your code.

- Missing a closing `)` on this line: `else if (calcDiceOne(i) < calcDiceTwo(i) {`
- `calcDiceOne`, and `calcDiceTwo` are number variables, not functions. You should simply move the randomization inside the loop.
- Alert only accepts one parameter (The message to alert). If you want to alert all the results, you should format and concatenate them like below.
- `playerTwoWon = playerTwoWon++;` does nothing. `playerTwoWon++` will return whatever `playerTwoWon` is at the time, and will then increment it internally. You then set that back to it's original value. Simply just use `playerTwoWon++` or `playerTwoWon = playerTwoWon + 1`.

See revised code below:

```js
var playerOneWon = 0;
var playerTwoWon = 0;
var Tie = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var diceOne = Math.random();
    var calcDiceOne = (diceOne * 6) + 1;
    calcDiceOne = Math.floor(calcDiceOne);

    var diceTwo = Math.random();
    var calcDiceTwo = (diceTwo * 6) + 1;
    calcDiceTwo = Math.floor(calcDiceTwo);
    
    if (calcDiceOne > calcDiceTwo) {
      playerOneWon++;
    }

    else if (calcDiceOne < calcDiceTwo) {
      playerTwoWon++; 
    }

    else if (calcDiceOne === calcDiceTwo) {
      Tie++;
    }
}

alert(playerOneWon + " " + playerTwoWon + " " + Tie)
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! that worked. Can you maybe explain the logic behind the fact I should had the variables inside the loop? This was my only actually problem that I missed and than tried to mess with my code to find solutions like adding (i) etc..

Comment: You need to create random dice for each iteration in order to compare (Later on in the loop to see if the players won). You're doing essentially 100 trials of rolling the dice, so each dice roll needs to be created at the top of the loop.